# How to use Sqlite with expo in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, android-sqlite

Does 'react-native-sqlite-storage' work with expo or it is compulsory to use expo-sqlite. I am trying to create an app which heavily depends on a database but for some reason 'react-native-sqlite-storage' shows me two error,

ERROR  TypeError: Cannot convert null value to object, js engine: hermes

and

ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Furthermore, there seems to be very little information regarding this error online and that's when I found out about expo-sqlite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use expo-sqlite (https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/)

Using react-native-sqlite-storage seems to be not an good idea:

1. You won’t be able to use [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) as it contains
   native code
2. The project seems to be no longer maintained

Technically you can use the module by building your own expo client or eject the app but you should **not** do that if it isn‘t really necessary.

Comment: thanks for the help. I have started using expo-sqlite but for some reason I am not able to open my database. I get an error which says Property 'db' doesn't exist, js engine: hermes. For this I have posted another question so could you please look into it as well, https://stackoverflow.com/q/76689691/19423789